# how to merge these two queries and adjust if else condition in mysql php

Tags: php

```
if($_SESSION['isstaff'] == 1){
    $qry1 = "select * from username where username ='".$_SESSION['username']."' and password='".$_SESSION['password']."' and status=1";
}else{
    $qry1 = "select * from pdetail where rollno =".$_SESSION['username']." and password='".$_SESSION['password']."' and remark=1";
}
```

fore.g.

```
select * from 
  if($_SESSION['isstaff'] == 1){username}else{pdetail} 
where username ='".$_SESSION['username']."' and  
      password='".$_SESSION['password']."' and 
      if($_SESSION['isstaff'] == 1){status=1}else{remark=1};
```

Comment: Please provide us with more info and reorder your question properly, so we can understand what your issue is. Also provide an example of what you've already tried ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take your time to read [ask] in order to get useful responses.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `case` expression, check out for the documentation below:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

It will result somewhat like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, (case when (action = 2 and state = 0) 
 THEN
      1 
 ELSE
      0 
 END)
 as state from tbl1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you can do this using [ternary operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in PHP:

```
//Determine if $isstaff is true or false
$isstaff = $_SESSION["isstaff"]==1 ? true : false;

$qry1 = "SELECT * FROM ".
    ($isstaff ? "`username` " : "`pdetail` ") . "WHERE ". //username or pdetail
    ($isstaff ? "`username` " : "`rollno` ") . " = '{$_SESSION['username']}' AND ". //username or rollno
    "`password` = '{$_SESSION['password']}' AND ".
    ($isstaff ? "`status` " : "`remark` ") . " = 1;"; //status or remark
```